# How to utilize Pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to load a CSV file but keep getting the following error

*UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 0: invalid start byte*

Here's my code:

```html
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv('refined5.csv', error_bad_lines=False, skiprows=[0])
```

The file can be found here:
jmp.sh/xKopnNi

I realize that this is a unicode conversion error I want python to load or skip this line so that the rest of the file will load.

Comment: I faced a similar issue while reading from a pickle file. I realized that I was using python2.7 . I changed it to use python3.6 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks bu I'm using 3.7

Comment: You need to know the encoding of the file. Be skeptical of all of these answers. Where did you get the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `encoding = 'latin1'` when reading the file.

```
Downloads$ python3
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 23 2018, 20:22:55)
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataset = pd.read_csv('refined5.csv', encoding = 'latin1')
>>> dataset
           human fall flat  1277.33
           0  ¡??æ? ??æª ????        1
```

Comment: It worked! 
You are my hero :-)
Now for the complete dataset I get the following message: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 15" Any tricks there?

Comment: Could you share the complete dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file in notepad and save it using UTF-8 coding. It worked for me when I had similar error.

Comment: Thanks. I just did and it workd. Still looking for a more conventional solution.